# Decoding unicode in tweets in R

Tags: r, unicode, tweets, rtweet

In my tweets, I am getting Unicode in angular brackets as:
 "U+0001F602" Loved my flip phones

I want unicode in the format: \U0001F602.
I used rtweet package for retrieving tweets. I am new in this area. I want to know can we filter out Retweets somehow to reduce redundancy in the dataset

> tweets = search_tweets(q="phones", n=5000, lang="en")
>   Searching for tweets...
>   Finished collecting tweets!
>   write_as_csv(tweets, filename ,prepend_ids=TRUE, na="",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

I tried without "fileencoding" parameter as well.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check?dput()). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: Modified. Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want to handle unicode or get rid of rtweets?

Comment: Main task is to handle unicode.

Comment: By searching for "Loved my flip phones", I was able to find a tweet with the character `U+0001F602`. The text part of the result is marked as `"UTF-8"` and contains the correct character `U+0001F602`. R in the Windows text console prints that with angle brackets, but RGui and RStudio as `"\U0001f602"`. Maybe this is just a printing (non-)issue.